# Race condition with bufio.NewWriter but not with io.MultiWriter

Tags: multithreading, go, race-condition, goroutine

I am looking at goroutine safety and I have the below code to illustrate. I get a race condition detected when I run the below code which is understandable.

```
var buffer1, buffer2 bytes.Buffer

// two writers to same buffer
writer1 = bufio.NewWriter(&buffer1)
writer2 = bufio.NewWriter(&buffer1)

c := func(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) {
    io.Copy(dst, src)
}

go c(writer1, os.Stdin)
go c(writer2, os.Stderr)
```

I got a **one time** race condition happen at runtime when I replace `bufio.NewWriter` with `io.MultiWriter` as seen below. But using the race condition detector doesn't show me any data races happening in the below code snippet.

```
var buffer1, buffer2, buffer3 bytes.Buffer

// two multiwriters writing to buffer3
writer1 = io.MultiWriter(&buffer3, &buffer1)
writer2 = io.MultiWriter(&buffer3, &buffer1)

c := func(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) {
    io.Copy(dst, src)
}

go c(writer1, os.Stdin)
go c(writer2, os.Stderr)
```

In my opinion, there is a visible race condition happening in the second case with the `io.MultiWriter`. is it safe and why is it seldomly occurring?

Comment: It seldom occurs if you trigger it seldomly.  A data race is never safe.

Comment: Define race condition, how did your output look like and what did you expect?

Comment: Thanks @JimB. I built with go race detector on ``go build -race`` and there was nothing detected.

Comment: Race detector has no false positives, doesn't mean it will catch every race.

Comment: @Tega: the race detector only detects races that happen. It' still up to you to test the code concurrently, just compiling the code isn't going to tell you anything. While your code does have a race condition, it's probably hard to trigger since it doesn't really make sense to read from `os.Stderr` in most cases.